# Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread. Only on a particular service layer method

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

```html
   
@Aspect
@Service("vendorNotificationService")
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class VendorNotificationServiceImpl implements vendorNotificationService {
}


@Repository("vendorNotificationDao")
public class VendorNotificationDaoImpl implements VendorNotificationDao{

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public List<VendorNotification> fetchAll(Integer startResult, Integer 
        maxResults) {
  log.info("in vendor Notification fetch all");
  Criteria cr = this.getSessionFactory().createCriteria(VendorNotification.class);
  if ((startResult != null) && (maxResults != null)
                    && (maxResults != 0)) {
                    cr.setFirstResult(startResult);
                    cr.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                }
     return cr.list();
 }
  
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public List<DtoVendorNotification> getAllNotification(DetachedCriteria dcForNotification) {
  log.info("inside getAllNotification");
  Criteria cr = this.getSessionFactory().createCriteria(VendorNotification.class,"vendorNotification");
  cr.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("vendornotification.id", dcForNotification));
  ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
  proList.add(Projections.property("vendornotification.id"),"id");
  cr.setProjection(proList);
  cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DtoVendorNotification.class));
  return cr.list();
 }
}
```

My other services and dao are working fine. I use 
`@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` on my service layer. Suddenly only one dao called `NotificationDao` has started giving problem. This `NotificationDao` has another method in which it saves an entity, and it works fine. The exception is thrown only when any criteria is created to fetch results.

I have also used `@Aspect` annotation on the same method for some of my requirements. Don't know if this is creating problem.

```html
2017-12-11 16:55:22 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:175 - committing
2017-12-11 16:55:23 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
2017-12-11 16:55:23 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
2017-12-11 16:55:23 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:246 - Releasing JDBC connection
2017-12-11 16:55:23 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:264 - Released JDBC connection
2017-12-11 16:55:23 INFO  VendorNotificationDaoImpl:36 - in vendor Notification fetch all
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
 at ather.inv.dao.impl.VendorNotificationDaoImpl.getSession(VendorNotificationDaoImpl.java:28)
 at ather.inv.dao.impl.VendorNotificationDaoImpl.fetchAll(VendorNotificationDaoImpl.java:37)
 at ather.inv.service.impl.VendorNotificationServiceImpl.fetchAll(VendorNotificationServiceImpl.java:47)
 at ather.inv.controllers.VendorController.vendorNotification(VendorController.java:30)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: try to add some code samples.. the working one and the faulty method. Stacktrace would also help

Comment: Thanks for your time. i have added, please see

Comment: the error seems to happen in VendorNotificationDaoImpl.fetchAll. Can you add the code? Also what propagation do you use on the Transactional? REQUIRES?

Comment: I do not use any propagation

Comment: Required is default

Answer (score 0):

I have used @Aspect on the same service. Removing that solved the error. If anyone come across this, please give your inputs.